# IE 8 emulation on mac

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

I currently only have macs for development. My site looks good in the Chrome, safari and firefox but not in IE 8. Normally I'd say too bad, use a proper browser, but that is probably not going to work with my user base. Are there ways to emulate IE 8 on the mac?
BTW if somebody wants to have a look: [here](http://www.dijkmeijer.com/ellen) is the site.

In IE 8 only the 1 first column is displayed. In chrome or firefox I don't see any warnings, apart from some javascript warnings which I fixed locally (but not on world wide web yet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I know to do this is to run Windows with a program like Parallels and use IE that way.

I would recommend running Windows 7 and IE 9.  IE 9 is not only a competent web browser, it can render pages as IE 7 or IE 8 by using the included developer tools.

Answer (score 6):

1. Install [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) (it's free and good) or another virtualizer (VMWare, Parallels)
2. Convert and use one of [these Microsoft VirtualPC VHDs](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en)
3. Test

Comment: Great tip! Users may want to use the [`ievms` software](https://github.com/xdissent/ievms) to automate this process, which is otherwise fairly complicated to do on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Use VirtualBox or VMware with a VM from Microsoft: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/

*"Test Microsoft Edge (EdgeHTML) and versions of IE8 through IE11 using free virtual machines you download and manage locally."*

Old answer from 2012:

There is [CrossOver](http://www.codeweavers.com/) (proprietary $51). It *"allows many Windows-based applications to run on Mac OS X using a compatibility layer"*. It is based on [Wine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29).

It works OK (JavaScript + Flash). They provide automatic installation for Internet Explorer 6 and 7.
For Internet Explorer 8 [one more step](http://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/browse/name?app_id=4225) is required to get what they call a CrossTie.

You can also try [WineBootler](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/) (free and based on Wine too) but it does not work very well (no JavaScript support).